# How do I properly use setprecision() to add ".00" to the end of an amount for money?

Tags: c++, cout, iomanip

I apparently don't know how to set precision. This code should print out the price for a car going through a tollbooth

```
void TollBooth::arrive(Car c)
{
  carcount += 1;
  int cost;
  int doors = c.getDoors();
  cost = 3 + doors;
  total+=cost;
  cout << setw(12) << left << "Car: "<< setw(8) <<c.getID()<< setw(8) 
    << "  Amount Due: $ " << setw(5) << fixed << right << setprecision(2) << cost << endl;
}
```

However what prints out is the "cost" without trailing zeroes.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519645/trouble-calculating-correct-decimal-digits/2519665#2519665

Comment: Even more related, if not a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623689/setprecision-is-confusing

Comment: [`std::setprecision`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) sets the number of _all_ digits to be shown, not only those appearing after the decimal point.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I think it allows you to specify the number of digits after the decimal when you use it with **fixed** ios manipulator.

Comment: @bkVnet Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

For your particular case it is not adding the trailing zeros because `cost` is declared as an `integer` in your code. You need to cast it to `double` or `float`(although it might result in data loss for some integer values).

```
cout << setw(12) << left << "Car: "<< setw(8) <<c.getID()<< setw(8) << "  Amount Due: $ " 
<< setw(5) << fixed << right << setprecision(2) << static_cast<double>cost << endl;
```

BTW you may want to read the links given in the comment section of your question.

Comment: _@bkVnet _ _"even though i don't see the point of making a price(monetary value) an integer."_ Well, check the link from my first comment.

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ Point very much taken. Thanks.

Comment: @bkVnet: Even if you want to think of money as non-integer, using floating-point value for storing money is a sure way to disaster. Fixed-point is a much better idea, which is represented by an integer anyway (i.e. just express it in terms of cents).

Comment: @bkVnet: I'd strongly recommend `double` over `float` here if you must use floating point. IEEE 32 bit `float` has sufficiently limited precision that you start getting data loss even for integer conversions around the 25 bit mark, which is inside the range of `int` (in a quick test in Python, `ctypes.c_float(16777217).value` gets you `16777216.0`).

Comment: @ShadowRanger You are right. I'll updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `setprecision`, just echo the trailing `.00` directly (and adjust the preceding `setw`):

```
void TollBooth::arrive(Car c)
{
    carcount += 1;
    int doors = c.getDoors();
    int cost = 3 + doors;
    total += cost;
    cout << setw(12) << left << "Car: "<< setw(8) <<c.getID()<< setw(8) << "  Amount Due: $ " 
    << setw(3) << right << cost << ".00" << endl;
}
```

You could cast to floating point, and for an `int` value, using `double` *should* be safe on all architectures I'm aware of. Don't cast to `float` though; [as I noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36725937/how-do-i-properly-use-setprecision-to-add-00-to-the-end-of-an-amount-for-mo#comment61036969_36726125), IEEE 32 bit floats don't have the precision to represent the entire range of `int` (e.g. `(1 << 24) + 1` becomes equal to `1 << 24` when cast to IEEE 32 bit `float`). Best to avoid the risk of a precision error when it's not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

As others wrote, the reason is that you are using ints instead of doubles, but anyway. Whether you can use doubles to represent currency is somwhat up to debate. I wouldn't do it, but for most non-financial software (like games, school projects, keeping track of your monthly income and expenses) it's good enough.

However, comminig back to your actual problem: If you want to format monetary values, you probably want to use [`std::put_money`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_money) instead of plain floating point formatting anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setprecision` and `showpoint`:

```
double a = 14;
cout << setprecision(4) << showpoint << a;
```

Output:

```
14.00
```

Downside is you would have to calculate the setprecision argument.